# TinyMCE toolbar select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Is it possible to change appearance of 'fontselect', 'fontsizeselect' and 'formatselect' selectboxes something like 'forecolor' and 'backcolor'? I mean replace default to icon with arrow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would want to start here [Custom toolbar button](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php) and use it to call the existing code for changing those things you want.